# compiling with cygwin/gfortran or ifort with acml

Tags: fortran, cygwin, gfortran, win64

I would like to compile my program linking to acml. In cygwin (win64) with gfortran linking to acml:

```
$ gfortran empty.f90 -L/c:/cygwin64/acml5.3.1/win64/lib/libacml_dll.lib
```

yields

```
/tmp/ccKechZN.o:empty.f90:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `drandinitialize_'
/tmp/ccKechZN.o:empty.f90:(.text+0xff): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `drandinitialize_'
/tmp/ccKechZN.o:empty.f90:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `drandgaussian_'
/tmp/ccKechZN.o:empty.f90:(.text+0x13b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `drandgaussian_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried a few other things with the help of the [documentation](http://fulla.fnal.gov/acml/html/Linking_002fWindows.html#Linking_002fWindows), but nothing has successfully allowed the compiler to link with acml. I also tried to link to the library by adding `-l acml_dll` and received the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lacml_dll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have verified that the .lib exists in the directory specified. Perhaps a related problem, I am also trying to execute the output from ifort linked to acml on win64. I am using "Intel 64 Visual Studio 2013 mode" command prompt to compile an example program that calls subroutines from acml (see [documentation](http://www.hpc.wm.edu/sciclone/documentation/software/math/ACML-5.3.1/html/Linking_002fWindows.html) for linking in win64):

```
ifort /libs:dll empty.f90 c:/AMD/acml5.3.1/ifort64_int64/lib/libacml__dll.lib
```

which yields

```
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 14.0.5.239 Build 20150212
Copyright (C) 1985-2014 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:empty.exe
-subsystem:console
empty.obj
```

At least with ifort the program compiles successfully. Then when I execute empty.exe I get the following error:

> The program can't start because libacml_dll.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I tried reinstalling acml 5.3.1 as well as trying acml 6.1.0, but encountered the same error upon execution.

Answer (score 0):

Just specifying the library path alone is not sufficient. You have to tell the compiler to link against the library as well. Simply add `-l acml_dll` to the compile options.

Additionally, specifying the library path with `-L` expects a path, not a file. So the complete command should look like

```
gfortran empty.f90 -L/c:/cygwin64/acml5.3.1/win64/lib/ -lacml_dll
```

When you run the program, the library needs to be found at runtime as well. The easiest way to achieve this is to use [`rpath`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath):

```
gfortran empty.f90 -L/c:/cygwin64/acml5.3.1/win64/lib/ -lacml_dll \
                   -Wl,-rpath=/c:/cygwin64/acml5.3.1/win64/lib/
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it cannot find `lacml_dll`. I confirmed that the directory exists and the library is located there.